# How can I convert audio from MP4 or FLV video files to mp3?

Tags: mp3, media, convert, mp4, flv

Is there an application that allows me to extract the audio from a MP4 or FLV video file and store it as an MP3 file for use in a portable media player?

Comment: technically you can't, but what you can do is extract the sound from the video into MP3 format...

Comment: Both `mp4` and `flv` video files contain `aac` audio. To have that audio as `mp3` is easy, but there may be some problems converting between lossy formats. The input and output bit-rates have to be considered. See the discussions in the different answers under [this question](http://superuser.com/q/593869/162573). Maybe the best solution would be to keep the audio in `aac` format, that is in the `m4a` container - more [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/294426/47206)

Comment: @cipricus Both `mp4` and `flv` video files **can contain sound in many formats** including `aac` and `mp3`. For example the [FLV container specification](http://audior.ec/blog/converting-flv-to-mp3-server-side-with-ffmpeg/) mentions no less than 15 types of supported sound codecs/types.

Comment: @OctavianNaicu - You are right. My comment was intended at promoting the idea of keeping the audio without conversion. That is a good idea no matter the format, but of course one should know beforehand what the specific audio format is there, by using a tool like mediainfo. (On the other hand,  as flv and mp4 are the common formats of youtube videos, which contain AAC audio, I had imagined the question was implicitly referring to youtube.)

Comment: I agree with you that the audio should not be converted if possible. I was trying to convey the idea that containers can hold audio data in different formats and you need to look at the format/codec not at the container. Depending on the source audio format one might need to transcode the audio (for example `aac` in `mp4` to `mp3` in `mp3`) OR just copy it over to the new container (`mp3` in `mp4 ` to `mp3` in `mp3`).

Answer (score 157, accepted):

You can do the same in 12.04 by using several software.

### Using WinFF

1. Install winff and libavcodec-extra first

   ```
    sudo apt-get install winff libavcodec-extra
   ```
2. Open Winff from dash

   [image]
3. Then in Winff window, do these

   1. Add file
   2. Select what catagory to convert (select Audio)
   3. Select Audio file format (mp3)
   4. Type the output folder for converted file

   [image]

   5. Then click the **Convert** button. You can also click **Options** button to file tune the audio format and other options.

   [image]

   [image]

### Using VLC

1. Install VLC and "libavcodec-extra" package first

   ```
   sudo apt-get install vlc libavcodec-extra
   ```
2. Open VLC from dash by pressing `Super` key and typing "VLC" there

   [image]
3. Then from top panel menu, Select **Media** → **Convert/Save**.

   [image]
4. Then Add file to convert in the new window. Then click **Convert** button.

   [image]
5. In the new window, Select the directory for output file, select the conversion profile (Audio mp3) and click **Start** button.

   [image]

### Using command line

1. First install the tools

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ffmpeg libavcodec-extra libav-tools
   ```

   If you are using
2. Use this simple command to extract the audio file

   ```
   avconv -i /input-file-name-with-path output-filename.mp3
   ```

   For example to convert the "How fast.ogg" video file into `how-fast.mp3` use this command:

   ```
   avconv -i /usr/share/example-content/Ubuntu_Free_Culture_Showcase/How\ fast.ogg how-fast.mp3
   ```

   See the [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/avconv.1.html) for more options and information.

### To Just extract audio

Check these answer

- https://askubuntu.com/a/234197/61218
- [ffmpeg to extract audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913032/ffmpeg-to-extract-audio-from-video)

Comment: I think in the command line the libavcodec-extra-53 package is important. Before I installed it, I do not succeded to convert to mp3.

Comment: @ArpaD wasn't that i said in the answer?

Comment: Sorry. I have not thought that it seems from my comment, that everything is bad in your description. I was just happy to realize, that with that package it is so easy from the command line. I will moderate myself.

Comment: @ArpaD no problem. I was confused with your comment. Thanks. I know now, it was verifying my answer

Comment: amazing nswer...!! so detailed and clear... thanks a lot... this really took me out from a big fix!!

Comment: Outstanding answer.  Nice work.

Comment: In older versions, of ubuntu, you can use sudo apt-get install winff libavcodec-extra-52   I also want to note, that winff can run from the command line, and for me, required root permissions to do the conversions.

Comment: This doesn't work now...`sudo apt-get install winff libavcodec-extra53` gives the following output: Package libavcodec-extra-53 is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libav-tools:i386 libav-tools

E: Package 'libavcodec-extra-53' has no installation candidate

Comment: @VineetKaushik you should just replace the `libavcodec-extra53` to `libavcodec-extra-54`. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Now I think it's 56. But why not just install the `libavcodec-extra` metapackage?

Comment: this answer is great, it just misses Sound Converter, imho the most easy way to do it !

Comment: +1 for `avconv`. I've been looking for a simple command-line way to do this for a long time!

Answer (score 68):

you can do it using ffmpeg. Install ffmpeg using following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg libavcodec-unstripped-52
```

The package libavcodec-unstripped-52 is available in Multiverse repo, so you will need to enable it.
After installing these packages, you can use a command like the one below to extract the audio as mp3:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -f mp3 -ab 192000 -vn music.mp3
```

The **-i** option in the above command is simple: it is the path to the input file. The second option **-f mp3** tells ffmpeg that the ouput is in mp3 format. The third option i.e **-ab 192000** tells ffmpeg that we want the output to be encoded at 192Kbps and **-vn** tells ffmpeg that we dont want video. The last param is the name of the output file.

Comment: I did some more searching on ffmpeg, I found this wonderful guide http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/19-ffmpeg-commands-for-all-needs

Comment: I prefer the newer audio/video converter avconv. syntax is similar to ffmpeg:  'avconv -i input.mp4 -vn -qscale 1 output.mp3'  ... -qscale 1 ensures maximum quality (and VBR) and the type of the encoder is deduced from the output file extension.

Comment: ffmpeg now comes from libav-tools.

Comment: Running this program, it says: *** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED *** This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead.

Comment: Nice answer, because ffmpeg can be used on mac os, and I don't need to switch to ubuntu :)

Comment: @M.Elmi ffmpeg is not deprecated if this answer is true: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9477756/813946

Comment: Weird how the new mp3 file  is even larger than source video:

`a@a-Inspiron-660 ~/Video $ ll _-M8J8urC_8Jw.mkv  music.mp3 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 a a 26844523 gen 23  2019 _-M8J8urC_8Jw.mkv
-rw-rw-r-- 1 a a 31069582 ott 26 12:02 music.mp3
a@a-Inspiron-660 ~/Video $ 
`

Answer (score 13):

soundconverter is another tool that can convert audio formats and also video to audio only:

[image: Install via the software center]

or via the terminal:

`sudo apt-get install soundconverter`

Comment: I had to do sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras to enable conversion to mp3s

Answer (score 9):

It is very easy to do with WinFF ([install it](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/winff)), which is a GUI for ffmpeg.

1. Click add.
2. Select a video file
3. In Convert to, select Audio
4. Select an audio codec
5. Click Convert. (Notice that the Convert button might sometimes disappear if the window is too small. Make the window larger if you don't see it)

Done. Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

**Audacity** can also open a flv file and export it as mp3, flac and other formats

[image]

[image]

---

My favorite way is to use `gnome-terminal -e "avconv -i %f %f.mp3"` in Thunar custom actions. Even better, to get a constant bitrate of 192 kbps:

`avconv -i %f -c:a libmp3lame -ac 2 -b:a 190k %f.mp3`

In fact the audio in a flv (and mp4) file is in `aac` format. To stay as close as possible to the quality of the original sound, consider using the `aac` in an `m4a` container. If the mp3 format is a must, consider the initial bitrate of the `aac` file when converting to mp3. More [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/288571/47206).

Answer (score 5):

[soundconverter [image: Install soundconverter]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/soundconverter) is another tool that can convert audio formats and also video to audio only.

It can be installed in the Software Center (by clicking the above link) or by running these commands in a Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install soundconverter
```

Comment: have you tested converting flv to mp3 in soundconverter? while converting mp4 video to mp3 works ok, in my case it works endlessly with no result to a flv file that winff converts in seconds

Comment: also install ubuntu-restricted-extras for mp3 conversion

Answer (score 3):

You can convert your media files using VLC player.
Load a media file => to convert: Menubar > Media > Convert/Save.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have been using VLC for a while but I didn't know of this feature

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with a simple command:
`ffmpeg -i yourVideoInput.mp4 theAudioOutput.mp3`

Comment: cant find aconv in latest ubuntu,   ffmpeg works as above

Answer (score 1):

[mkvtoolnix](https://mkvtoolnix.download/doc/mkvmerge.html) is a good package, it can extract by tracks, chapters or specific timings at the same time.

```
mkvmerge -i <input_video>
```

> Track ID 0: video (MPEG-4p10/AVC/h.264)
>   Track ID 1: audio (AC-3/E-AC-3)
>   Track ID 2: audio (AC-3/E-AC-3)

You want to extract TrackID 2 by each chapters (assume the long video)

```
mkvmerge -o <output_audio> --audio-tracks 2 --no-video --split chapters:all <input_video>
```

You get numbered files, output_audio001, output_audio002...

Then convert each audio file to mp3

Answer (score 0):

**Transmageddon**

You can also use Transmagedon Video Converter to convert video file to sound file.

[image: Install via the software center]

Or in trminal:

```
sudo apt-get install transmageddon
```

To convert to MP4, you have to select in `Choose Video Codec` as `No Video`.

Can convert to `.ogg` by selecting the `Presets` as Ogg.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used VLC media player to convert a .flv file to a .mp4/mp3 file.
Audacity failed at even loading the complete file. It could load only the first 8 seconds and I could export the audio.
But, VLC was the fastest!
Let every other piece of software be!