# How to convert Video to Mp3 in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, video, mp3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert a Video to MP3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80954/how-to-convert-a-video-to-mp3)

I am using 12.04 . I have found a question that have the solution

[How can I convert audio from MP4 or FLV video files to mp3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80954/how-to-convert-a-video-to-mp3)

But when i tried the answer i got this problem .

```
subbu@subbu-300E4Z-300E5Z-300E7Z:~$ sudo apt-get install ffmpeg libavcodec-unstripped-52.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libavcodec-unstripped-52.
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libavcodec-unstripped-52.'
```

Comment: To whoever has voted to reopen this: Can you explain why this should not be considered a duplicate of [that question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/80954/how-to-convert-a-video-to-mp3)? (It seems to me that this should be merged, rather than reopened.)

Comment: @EliahKagan yup! thats me. Reason : he got an Error and no solution for that .

Answer (score 9):

Open vlc media player. Then file - convert/save and select the video file you need. Then add the destination (should be example.mp3 file). Choose the profile: audio - mp3 so you save only the sound of the video. Good luck.

Comment: Learnt something new about wonderful VLC media player. Thanks you.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with Audacity.

> Audacity is a multi-track audio editor for Linux/Unix, MacOS and
>   Windows. It is designed for easy recording, playing and editing of
>   digital audio. Audacity features digital effects and spectrum analysis
>   tools. Editing is very fast and provides unlimited undo/redo.
>
> Supported file formats include Ogg Vorbis, MP2, MP3, WAV, AIFF, and
>   AU.<sup>1</sup>

To download and install click the image below.

[image: Install via the software center]

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Ubuntu Apps Directory](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/audacity/)</sup>

For more help, [this YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-wpWEDfozE) shows how to use Audacity to perform the conversion.