# How to extract audio from Webm without transcoding?

Tags: sound, convert, extract, ogg-vorbis, webm

Audio within `mp4` and `flv` files is `AAC`, and a proper container for that is `m4a`. So, in order to extract sound from `mp4` and `flv` I use a command like

```
gnome-terminal -e "parallel avconv -i '{}' -map 0:1 -c:a copy '{}.m4a' ::: %F"
```

and add it to Thunar's custom actions.
More [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/288571/47206) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/294426/47206).

How to achieve that for `Webm`? (I read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebM) that the audio contained is `Vorbis`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering the answers linked (in my question above), and the answers linked therein (especially [this answer and the comment under it](https://askubuntu.com/a/235912/47206), I dare think that the same line of command can be used in the same way for extracting `ogg-vorbis` out of `Webm` video. I welcome comments on whether this is the case.

To be able to convert multiple files, install `parallel` (see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/288571/47206)).

```
 sudo apt-get install parallel
```

And then, just adapting the mentioned command to extract in `ogg-vorbis`.

```
parallel avconv -i '{}' -map 0:1 -c:a copy '{}.ogg' ::: %F
```

(The idea is to get the same audio content as in the original `Webm` - and checking both the `Webm` and the output `ogg` with [`mediainfo`](https://askubuntu.com/a/252775/47206), I see the same audio specifications.)

This command can be used [in Thunar's custom actions](https://askubuntu.com/q/18367/47206) in a form similar to

```
xfce4-terminal -e "parallel avconv -i '{}' -map 0:1 -c:a copy '{}.ogg' ::: %F"
```

---

UPDATE:

I now prefer a different line of command, without the terminal and `parallel`:

```
bash -c 'avconv -i "$0" -map 0:1 -c:a copy "${0%%.*}".ogg' %f
```

Comment: `mkvextract` from the `mkvtoolnix` package can also be used, but while you are not using MP4Box for the MP4 container, you might want to stick with ffmpeg.