# DVD and VCD to Mp3

Tags: format-conversion, vcd, dvd-audio

Is there any package that allows me to rip the DVD and VCD to MP3. I have few DVD and VCDs that I would like to put into MP3 Disc. Recording in software like Audacity is not an option for me. Commandline or GUI that does not matter as long as it works

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/80954/how-to-convert-a-video-to-mp3

Comment: Upvoted!
I am testing sound converter, if it works I will request you to put it as answer and I will accept that!

Comment: I have no idea if this also works for vcd ;)

Comment: Thats why I will try to make sure that it works on vcd

Comment: does not work at all!
Trying Format Factory with Wine!

Comment: does not work also. I wonder if there is anything else in Linux that works!

Answer (score 0):

Usually if you can play media, then you can also extract and store (dump) its contents. This is what you would use for DVDs:

```
mplayer dvd://$SourceTrack -dvd-device "${SourceVtsPath}/${SourceVts}" -aid "128" -dumpaudio -dumpfile "$Outfile"
```

Searching online brings up the following example from the [manual](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/vcd.html):

```
mplayer vcd://2 -cdrom-device /dev/hdc
```

The most simple way of getting MP3 output of the [MP2 audio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vcd#Audio) dump would be:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp2 output.mp3
```

Or it wasn't standards compliant and you already have MP3.