# How can I record audio while it is playing?

Tags: sound, audio-recording

Is it possible to record playing audio on an Ubuntu 16.04 laptop? I mean part of audio the from a video file or playing music.

As requested in comments:

Output of `arecord -l`

```
$ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: 92HD87B1/3 Analog [92HD87B1/3 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I tried

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:0 -t 360 na_re_full.wav
```

The output was just a blank file (of chosen length) with some random noise. Nothing was recorded from the streaming music :(

```
$ arecord -L
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
sysdefault:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, 92HD87B1/3 Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, 92HD87B1/3 Analog
    Front speakers
surround21:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, 92HD87B1/3 Analog
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, 92HD87B1/3 Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, 92HD87B1/3 Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, 92HD87B1/3 Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, 92HD87B1/3 Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, 92HD87B1/3 Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, 92HD87B1/3 Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, 92HD87B1/3 Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, 92HD87B1/3 Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, 92HD87B1/3 Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/80954/how-can-i-convert-audio-from-mp4-or-flv-video-files-to-mp3possible duplicate of

Comment: Can be done with FFmpeg, can you give the results of `arecord -L`? Details are here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/ALSA

Comment: @kenn what if the playing audio is being streamed ?

Comment: @andrew.46 Thank you. Is it possible to get the output as .mp3 ? Updated the post with aredcord -l output

Comment: @user227495 Sure is but first to capture any sound at all :). Make the arecord command with the option `-L` rather than `-l`.

Comment: @andrew.46 , updated the original post. :)

Comment: @user227495 So perhaps: `ffmpeg -f alsa -i sysdefault:CARD=PCH -t 10 out.wav` ?

Comment: @andrew.46 Not working :* I even tried using Audacity with sound card as `default` , `sysdefault`, `pulse` and by manually selecting the card from drop down. All of them gives blank audio with some noise

Comment: Finally, found a workaround. Removed headphone and tried recording source as `default` in Audacity. That worked :)

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271411). If you want to record streaming media I suggest you rephrase your question to clarify *which stream* you want to capture to allow solutions that capture it directly rather than record its playback.

Answer (score 3):

1. Use Audacity
2. Remove any headphones/mic plugged in
3. Use recording source as `default` ( if not working, try trial and error )
4. Click the " Record " button ( a maroon dot )
5. You can see the GUI listing variations if audio is recording
6. Start and stop at desired points
7. Save as Audacity project
8. Delete unwanted part of the audio
9. Use File > Save other > Export as mp3 to your desired location

[image]