# How to demux an mp4 file

Tags: 12.04, mp4, avconv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I extract audio track from video file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41749/how-can-i-extract-audio-track-from-video-file)

I have an mp4 file, and I want to separate the video and audio to separate files.  I know the audio file in the mp4 file is aac.  How do I losslessly extract the audio file?

I think I am supposed to use avconv?